# Getting ServletContext Attribute "javax.servlet.context.tmpdir" in Controller

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I'm really new to Spring and Spring MVC and I'm working on a kind of test program that uploads a file, writes it to the servlet's temporary working directory, and then passes that file to the rest of the program (which is a Spring Batch Job and works fine). My problem currently is figuring out how to get the location of the temporary file within my Controller used to configure Spring's DispatcherServlet.

The code I've seen online to get the temporary file location is this:

```
File directory = (File)getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tmpdir");
File file = File.createTempFile("prefix", ".tmp", directory);
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
```

But from what I've seen so far it's not possible to use getServletContext in the Controller class I'm using to configure the servlet.

Any advice on how to get what I want or on other ways to handle this are greatly appreciated. If you need any more details just ask.

Comment: You should be using the constant [`ServletContext.TEMPDIR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#TEMPDIR) instead of a hardcoded attribute name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try  injecting `ServletContext` into your controller with `@Autowired` annotation and access it in your method.

```
class XController {
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

}
```

Comment: When I do this it looks like servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tmpdir") is returning **null**. Is there anything else I need to do to get the autowired ServletContext to work? Sorry, I'm still getting my head around all the features of Spring.

Comment: I hope `javax.servlet.context.tmpdir` is defined in your web.xml, isn't it ? And it will be `String` rather than `File`.You should use `new File(attributeValue);`

Comment: Turns out it was null because the attribute is javax.servlet.context. **tempdir** and not **tmpdir**. Unfortunate that the example I found had a typo in it. I can see the file location being read correctly now. Also, `getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir")` returns a `File`, not a `String`. Thanks for the help! I've still got some errors but at least this is solved.